# How can I install Android Studio as a package?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, android-studio

For some bizarre reason official instructions are for manual install: https://developer.android.com/studio/install#linux

`sudo apt-get install android-studio`

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                
Building dependency tree                                                                                                                                                                     
Reading state information... Done                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                             
No apt package "android-studio", but there is a snap with that name.                                                                                                                         
Try "snap install android-studio"                                                                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                                                                             
E: Unable to locate package android-studio
```

The proposed snap - in addition to all snap awfulness - is version `2021.3.1.17` (which is [no longer usable for me](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#android_gradle_plugin_and_android_studio_compatibility))

Comment: Ironically I have an option to delete question id "duplicate" box, but I cannot use it as this question is blocked from being deleted.

Comment: Also, it is not really a duplicate as I am asking about package specifically as, installing using prepared packages is much better than manual installation drudgery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google does not allow redistribution of their Android Studio software by Linux distros.

From the [Android Studio License](https://developer.android.com/studio/terms):

> 3.4 You may not use the SDK for any purpose not expressly permitted by the License Agreement.  Except to the extent required by applicable third party licenses, you may not copy (except for backup purposes), modify, adapt, redistribute, decompile, reverse engineer, disassemble, or create derivative works of the SDK or any part of the SDK.

Therefore there will be no fully-inclusive packages in the Ubuntu repositories while Google offers the software under the current license. Some folks create PPAs with packaged versions of Android Studio for a while until they lose interest in maintaining the package (or until they get nasty letters from Google lawyers). Other folks have created snap packages and flatpak packages that work very well for most.

An installer-only package may possible that does not violate the license; that's a common workaround. However, AskUbuntu volunteers will not create such a package for you. Most deb packages are created by Debian volunteers, not by Canonical nor Google nor other companies. If you want to try your hand at it, start your journey at http://mentors.debian.net.

Comment: It seems that it should be still possible to make package that on the first run automatically obtains AS (I am fine with packages that are not `.deb` or require internet for the install). Or Google could make own package.

Comment: Edited to address your comment.

Comment: `However, AskUbuntu volunteers will not create such a package for you`
Oh, I know. I just wanted to start from checking whether anyone did this already - doing something already done because I was unaware that it is solved problem is not my favourite activity.